# Covering space of wedge of two circles generated by $\{a^{3},b^{2},aba^{-1}b^{-1}\}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I've been drawing graphs for too long trying to figure it out. I know how to find the generating set using maximal trees, but is there a trick for the reverse problem of given a generating set, come up with the graph?

Answer (score 1):

[If it is still of any importance, here is the picture with the graph you were interested in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEp79.png)